# Durandal JS: typing url without hash give HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

Tags: hash, http-status-code-404, durandal

I am building a SPA application using Durandaljs. When I enter a URL WITHOUT hash, it shows the error: `HTTP error 404.0 - NOT FOUND.` However, it is working fine WITH hash.

Example:

```
www.domain.com/page =>  HTTP error 404.0 - NOT FOUND
www.domain.com/#page = > working fine.
```

How can I map the `www.domain.com/page` to `www.domain.com/#page`?

Answer (score 6):

In order for `pushState` to work correctly in your app (including deep linking), you must configure the router for pushState **and** tell the server to ignore all but certain paths/routes.

The server should ignore paths that contain resources or services used by your SPA, and should always send the `Durandal.cshtml` *(or whatever you name it)* for these ignored routes.

These routes should be ignored even if there's additional route info in the request. This will allow for deep linking using pushState-style URLs.

Here's the MVC routing from a Durandal-based app I recently completed:

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.Ignore("{resourcedir}/{*resource}", 
        new {resourcedir = @"(api|breeze|app|scripts|content|assets|signalr)"});
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{*sparoute}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Durandal", action = "Index"});
}
```

Basically, we're telling the server to ignore any requests that start with:

- api/
- breeze/
- app/
- scripts/
- content/
- assets/
- signalr/

We're ignoring `api`, `breeze` and `singlar` because WEBApi and SignalR will handle those requests. Also, `app`, `scripts`, `content`, and `assets` are ignored because the underlying ASP.NET engine will serve those requests.

The final statement (`routes.MapRoute`) causes all non-ignored requests to send back the default page (the only real page in the SPA).

For example, `www.domain.com/page` will send the same response from the server as if you'd asked for `www.domain.com/`. Once the SPA loads and Durandal's `router/history` has initialized, the suffix is converted to hash if needed (like you're using IE) and is then dispatched through the router.

Note that if your application is not rooted at `/`, you need to specify the root path. You should also include `hashChange: true` so that your application works in IE, like this:

```js
router.activate({ pushState: true, hashChange: true, root: '/approot' })
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, I'm using it in my latest Durandal site which is based on the [DurandalAuth](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth) template.

When you are initializing your router, set `pushState: true`, like this:

```js
return router.map([
    { route: 'somroute', moduleId: 'somroute', title: 'Home', nav: true, hash: "#somroute" }
  ])
  .buildNavigationModel()
  .mapUnknownRoutes("notfound", "notfound")
  .activate({ pushState: true });
```

You can see a working example on my site: [noadou](http://noadou.com/home/info)

Comment: What settings are you using on the server side? I tried this and my client is now broken with 'route not found' error

Comment: I dont have the source available at this time but check out the template i linked to and you should see what hes doing in there.